# What is the correct way to convert a Shape to a Rectangle2D.Double?

Tags: java

I have the need to transform (rotate) a `Rectangle2D.Double`. However, I don't just need to draw the shape, I also need to keep the transformed rectangle as an object so that I can use `.intersects()` and other methods. This is the current way I am transforming it

```
private Rectangle2D.Double transform(Rectangle2D.Double rect) {

    // make a new transform
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    // apply the transformation
    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta), rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);
    // get the resulting Shape
    Shape s = transform.createTransformedShape(hitbox);
    //return the finalized Rectangle
    // ?
}
```

Now, one would think that the following would work

```
Rectangle2D.Double newRect = new Rectangle2D.Double();
newRect.setFrame(transform.createTransformedShape(rect).getBounds2D());
```

However, when drawn this appears to not rotate the rect at all, but instead scale it by very large amounts (140 times as large).

So the question is: How do I get that `Shape`, which by the way when drawn appears to be transformed correctly, into the correct form, which is a `Rectangle2D.Double`?

If it isn't possible then what is a good alternative that still has the `.intersects()` and similar methods?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux is correct: When the rectangle is rotated, then it is no longer a `Rectangle2D` with an (x,y) position and a (width,height). In order to perform intersection tests with a rotated rectangle, you have several options: 1. Creating an own `RotatedRectangle` class that is described e.g. by 4 corner points. 2. Write a general `Shape-Shape` intersection test. 3. Convert the resulting `Shape` into an `Area`, and use `Area#intersect` and `Area#isEmpty` to perform intersection tests. These options vary greatly in effort and performance. More details about your use case are needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rectangle2D` is axis aligned. It cannot be turned. Try using a `Path2D` instead. There is a nice constructor that seems to be doing exactly what you want:
[`Path2D.Double(Shape shape, AffineTransform transform)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#Path2D.Double(java.awt.Shape,%20java.awt.geom.AffineTransform))

```
private Path2D.Double transform(Rectangle2D.Double rect) {

    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    double angle = Math.toRadians(theta);
    transform.rotate(angle, rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);

    return new Path2D.Double(rect, transform);
}
```

Also note that your `toRadians(toRadians(theta))` is very suspicious and makes your angles very tiny.